# Input NxN matrix by the user

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, input, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to convert my inputted data from

```
g.addEdge(0, 1, 7) 
 g.addEdge(1, 2, 9) 
 g.addEdge(2, 0,14)
```

into

```
g.graph = [
        [ 0,  7,  0], 
        [ 0,  0,  9], 
        [ 14, 0, 0,],  
    ]
```

simply, the first and second number as the coordinate to place the last number.

I'm begging for your help, please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prim's Minimum Spanning Tree on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758530/prims-minimum-spanning-tree-on-python)

Comment: Please don't SPAM by creating duplicates of questions you've already asked. Instead, take the time to improve your question and there are better chances you'll get an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try to create matrix NxN where N is number of edges. You can create matrix as list that contains lists. After that make `addEdge` function that will just put last argument on x and y positions that are represented with first and second argument.

Maybe something like this:

```
g.graph = [[0 for x in range(N)] for y in range(N)] 

def addEdge(x, y, num):
   g.graph[x][y] = num
```

Also, I don't think your example is right because `x` and `y` coordinates aren't right, please check all that.